# Android - How to change the animation of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to change the way MyApp comes from background and shows to the user. I've overridden onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

I'd like the same animation of the android apps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJ35v-wn5zU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
}
```

Take a look at Slide Up-Slide Down:

Slide Up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:zAdjustment="top">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

Slide Down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Fade in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
   android:toAlpha="1.0" 
   android:duration="1000" 
   />
```

Fade Out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
android:toAlpha="0.0" 
android:duration="1000" />
```

Grow from middle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="800" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="50%"
        android:duration="800"/>
</set>
```

Shrink to Middle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="800" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="800"/>
</set>
```

Push Right In:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="800"/>        
</set>
```

Push Right Out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="800"/>
</set>
```

**P.S:** change `android:duration:` value to get desired delayed effect